# require help to bind button after button click & data is coming from retrofit2 api call

Tags: android, retrofit2

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("MaidDetails.ashx")
    Call<jsonResponse> fn_GetMaidDetails(@Field("ClientID") int ClientID, @Field("MaidID") int MaidID, @Field("HashKey") String HashKey);



@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MaidViewHolder maidViewHolder, int i) {

    final Maids Maid = Maids.get(i);
    context = maidViewHolder.ltl_Name.getContext();

    maidViewHolder.ltl_Name.setText(Maid.getMaid_Name());
    maidViewHolder.ltl_Type.setText(Maid.getMaid_Type());
    maidViewHolder.ltl_Locality.setText(Maid.getMaid_Locality());
    maidViewHolder.ltl_City.setText(Maid.getMaid_City());
    maidViewHolder.ltl_Age.setText(Maid.getMaid_Age());
    maidViewHolder.ltl_Experience.setText(Maid.getMaid_Experience());
    maidViewHolder.ltl_Address.setText(Maid.getMaid_Address());
    maidViewHolder.ltl_Date.setText(Maid.getMaid_Date());

    maidViewHolder.btn_MobileNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            int iMaidID = Maid.getMaid_ID();

            Button btn_MobileNo = (Button)view;

            fn_GetMaidDetails(iMaidID);

            Toast.makeText(context, "After - " + strResponseText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}



protected void fn_GetMaidDetails(int iMaidID){

    preferences = new SharedPrefs(context);
    int iAccountID = preferences.GetAccountID();

    String strHashKey = Library.fn_GenerateMD5(String.valueOf(iAccountID));

    MaidApi objApi = RetrofitClient.getRetrofit().create(MaidApi.class);
    Call<jsonResponse> call = objApi.fn_GetMaidDetails(iAccountID, iMaidID, strHashKey);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<jsonResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<jsonResponse> call, Response<jsonResponse> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                jsonResponse objResponse = response.body();

                if (objResponse.getResponse_Identity() > 0) {

                    strResponseText = objResponse.getResponse_Text();

                    Toast.makeText(context, "Before - " + strResponseText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                else
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(context, PackagesActivity.class);
                    context.startActivity(i);
                }

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(context, "3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<jsonResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "4", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}
```

I want to set button text after

```
if (objResponse.getResponse_Identity() > 0) {
    //set button text = objResponse.getResponse_Text();
}
```

Comment: What's your issue with setting button's text?

Comment: Button is not accessible from within retrofit call back.. and button is in MaidViewHolder

Answer (score 0):

'you can do it like this'

```
button.setText(objResponse.getResponse_Text().toString());
```

or

```
button.setText(objResponse.getResponse_Text());
```

Comment: Button is not accessible from within retrofit call back.. and button is in MaidViewHolder.. this code is inside Retrofit Adapter class

Comment: Make the button static and call it with class name anywhere. like in mainclass 'static Button button' and call it mainclass.button.setText(your text)